# Disable home key in keyboard

Tags: keyboard, xinput, xmodmap, shortcut-keys

My home key keeps pressing every time I use my laptop's keyboard so I am using an external keyboard right now, disabling the entire laptop keyboard. But I want to use the laptop's keyboard as I feel comfortable.

Used `sudo showkey`

and found the home key keycode and tried

`xmodmap -e 'keycode <value>='` but it doesn't work for home key

Is there any other way to disable a specific key(home key)?

Comment: make a keyboard shortcut for home key  in settings, and make it do nothing .

Comment: Only Home key couldn't be selected for shortcut key

Comment: ahh, I suspected as such, and that it might be worth a try. next idea is to remove the actual  home and see if you can play with the actual connections. or buy a new keyboard for your laptop and put it in (assume the issue is in the keyboard itself).. does it do that on a live CD? ruling out software issues (not likely). also Settings, Accessibility, and play with the keyboard repeat rate.

Comment: also you could at least try the software solution https://askubuntu.com/search?q=title%3Akeyboard+title%3Adisable+title%3Akey

Answer (score 0):

Quite obviously you have a hardware defect; it's time to replace that laptop keyboard. This is not anything that can be expected to be fixed by software.

Comment: I know its a hardware defect but I was looking if I can just disable that key everything else works fine

Comment: I don't think the keyboard electronics can identify which key was pressed if one of them keeps sending spurious electrical signals. I don't think trying to "silence" one particular key on the OS level can work if there is a defect on the hardware level.